# How to retrieve data points from chart image?

Tags: python, image, plot

I have some time series plots I've done a long time ago that I would like to improve in terms of graphics and style. However, I didn't save the raw data and I cannot recover them.

So I was wondering, is there a way to retrieve data points from a chart image (e.g. *png* file)? like I input an image and I get a csv/dataframe/array with pairs of x,y coordinates?

To give an idea, that's the kind of images I would like to convert:

[image]

I've seen this [GRABIT](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7173-grabit) could potentially work but I'm not familiar with MatLab. Is there anything python-based or possibly some web tools?

Preferences:

- work on linux systems (in particular ubuntu)
- doesn't require installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a little and simple software develop here in Brazil that can do this kind of thing.

You have to download in the following link:
http://paginapessoal.utfpr.edu.br/lasouza/analise-nao-linear-de-estruturas/Pega%20Ponto%201.0.exe/view

You can load the image, specify the origin and set the x and y labels. After you can retrieve the points that you clicked on the image.

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo :) I forgot to mention I work on a linux system (ubuntu). Does this work on linux?

Comment: I don't know. But I have found a web application here: https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/. It worked for me.

Comment: That's nice! It's more manual than I would have hoped, but I acknowledge I was hoping for something close to magic basically. Anyway that is a good solution and I found very useful the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7GbGdMvopU). Thanks :)